# How can I wait until DownloadManager is complete?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

This is the code I'm currently using

```
                String iosjiUrl = "http://modapps.com/NotoCoji.ttf";
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(iosjiUrl));
                request.setDescription("Sscrition");
                request.setTitle("Somle");
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "NotoColorji.ttf");

// get download service and enqueue file
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                manager.enqueue(request);
```

I'm not able to find a way for me to wait until the file is downloaded.

I also tried figuring out how to go about doing ASync but couldn't figure that out either =/

Thanks again!

Comment: you can use post execute in asyntask

Comment: Try this article http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to detect when the download finishes:

```
public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            //Show a notification
        }
    }
}
```

and register it in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".DownloadBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: It's a broadcast receiver. You'll have to create a new class and save it as `DownloadBroadcastReceiver.java`

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry I'm like super retarded about Android Apps and Android Studio.What directory should I putt the first code block in? And where in the manifest should I put the second code block?

Comment: You can put `DownloadBroadcastReceiver.java` in the same directory where you have your other `java` files like `MainActivity.java`. And same for the `AndroidManifest.xml` declaration, put it below your `Activity` declarations.

Comment: You're honestly amazing. Okay one last stupid stupid question. How exactly do I know use this in my `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: By registering it the `AndroidManifest` file will automatically enable the Receiver's `onReceive()` to be invoked whenever the `DownloadManger`'s download operation is complete. So whatever you need to do after that, write that code in the `if` block of `onReceive()` as posted in my answer. That is where the comment is written to show a notification.

Answer (score 1):

```html
A Broadcast intent action sent by the download manager when a download completes so you need to register a receiver for when the download is complete:

To register receiver

registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

and a BroadcastReciever handler

BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        // your code
    }
};

You can also create AsyncTask to handle the downloading of big files

Create a download dialog of some sort to display downloading in notification area and than handle the opening of the file:

protected void openFile(String fileName) {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),"MIME-TYPE");
    startActivity(install);
}

you can also check the sample link
```

[sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java)